# Use JSbin.com or CSSDesk offline?

Tags: html, css

I dont know if it's the right place to ask this but...

Is there a way to use JSbin.com or CSSDesk.com offline
Or are there a software that can make live editing (if i can call it like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying out adobe brackets, its nice and lightweight, although its still experimental it does work fine.

you can get the installer here: http://download.brackets.io/

And it features live editing of html + css + javascript using your browser.